# Find specific folders and then change their ownership

Tags: find, chown, ownership

I'm running into security issues with multiple Wordpress websites, and I need to recursively change the ownership (and permissions) for folder "wp-content" (and whatever is inside them).

I need to find all the folders named `wp-content` (there are several) and change them and all their contents so that they're owned by `nginx:nginx` with permissions 755 for folders and 644 for files.

I can't figure out a way to find those folders and then change the ownership.

Any clues? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GNU `find` and GNU `xargs` to search for the `wp-content` directories and pass the result NUL-terminated to a shell script:

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -name 'wp-content' -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
  for dir; do
    # change user and group recursively to nginx
    chown -R nginx:nginx "$dir"

    # change dirs to 755
    find "$dir" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

    # change files to 644
    find "$dir" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
  done
' sh
```

---

Alternatively, you could save the script part in a shell script `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir; do
  # change user and group recursively to nginx
  chown -R nginx:nginx "$dir"

  # change dirs to 755
  find "$dir" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

  # change files to 644
  find "$dir" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
done
```

Then make the shell script executable with

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

and run `find` (not necessarily the GNU implementation) using the `-exec` action and pass the result to the script:

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -name 'wp-content' -exec ./myscript.sh {} +
```

Comment: GNU's `-print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '...' sh` could be replaced with the standard `-exec sh -c '...' {} +` here. You'd probably want to make it `-prune -exec ...` as there's no point looking for more `wp-content` dirs inside the `wp-content` ones.

Comment: You can also use `chmod u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX` to cover both directory and regular files in the same `chmod` invocation (still can't use `chmod -R` though if you don't want to change the permissions of files that are neither regular nor directory).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . '(' -name wp-content -type d -o \
                    -path '*/wp-content/*' '(' -type d -o -type f ')' \
                ')' -exec chown nginx:nginx {} + \
                    -exec chmod u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX {} +
```

That way, you're crawling the directory only once and running as few invocations of `chown` and `chmod` as necessary and only changing the ownership/permissions of directory and regular files (excluding symlinks, devices, fifos...).

With some `find` implementations, you can simplify `'(' -type d -o -type f ')'` to `-type f,d`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using below command as well.

```
find some-folder-path -type d -name wp-content -exec chown new-user:new-group {} \;
```

The above command will change ownership and group of all folders having name wp-content.

```
find some-folder-path -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find some-folder-path -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

The above command will change permission of files to 644 and of folders to 755.